# Is there a built-in function to multiply each matrix line by an array?

Tags: matrix

Let us suppose a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and a vector $\mathbf{b}$.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
                      a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
                      a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and a vector $\mathbf{b}$
$$b = \begin{bmatrix}b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3}\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to create a matrix $\mathbf{C}$ whose lines be the lines of $\mathbf{A}$ multiplied by $\mathbf{b}$, yielding

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}b_1 & a_{12}b_2 & a_{13}b_3\\
                      a_{21}b_1 & a_{22}b_2 & a_{23}b_3\\
                      a_{31}b_1 & a_{32}b_2 & a_{33}b_3
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

For it, I am using a `Do` loop, as follows

`Do[C[[i, ;;]] = A[[i, ;;]]*b, {i, 1, Length@A}]`

Does anyone know a built-in function able to do that?

Comment: Just map a vector multiplication over the rows of A: `b#&/@A`

Comment: `A.DiagonalMatrix[b]` ?

Comment: Thanks, @wxffles and LouisB, the both approach worked. The wxffles's approach is faster, but I did not understand the syntax. Could you explain, please?

Comment: For large, numerica matrices, `A.DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[b]]` might be faster.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, both A and b are larges arrays. Thank you for that tip. Any millisecond would be important to me.

Comment: You might also be interested in reading [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a brief comparison for medium-sized, dense numerical arrays:

```
n = 5000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];

r1 = b # & /@ A; // RepeatedTiming // First

r2 = A.DiagonalMatrix[b]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r3 = A.DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[b]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r4 = Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}, {v, _Real, 1}}, u v,
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
      ][A, b]; // RepeatedTiming // First

r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

> 0.320
>
> 1.70
>
> 0.094
>
> 0.080
>
> True

The problem of the second method is that it has complexity $O(n^3)$. All the others are of order $O(n^2)$. The last method is both vectorized and parallelized. That gives it a slight edge over the third method for this example and on my machine (a somewhat dated 4-Core Haswell CPU).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Adding `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` I got 0.088 s, while not using it I got 0.073. Another thing that I noticed it was that adding `CompilationTarget -> "C"` I got a worse time too. Do you know why?

Comment: Hm. To my knowledge, `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` should have no effect _unless_ `CompilationTarget -> "C"` is set _and_ the code has a specific structure (e.g., when `Compile`GetElement` occurs). So I would blame that to "fluctuations". Or maybe your computer ran hot and the CPU is throttling...^^. `CompilationTarget -> "C"` should do no good because `Times`, when called upon packed arrays already calls optimized, vectorized libraries; so compiling the call to that library once more adds just calling overhead. And maybe a couple of superfluous internal copy operations...

Comment: I don't had ran using `CompilationTarget -> "C"` and `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`. Using the both I got 0.22 s, the same time of `r1`. Did my computer get crazy? :O

Comment: Ah, also have in mind that `CompilationTarget -> "C"` has quite a lot of overhead because it has to _compile_ the function with your system's C-compiler. Per default, `Compile` just runs the code in the `"WVM"` (Wolfram Virtual Machine); that is not as fast as running a compiled library but preparing the code for that takes only a couple of milliseconds.